# SQL Convert to GMT DateTime

Tags: sql, time

I want to convert my record entries from datetime+OFFSET to datetimeZ directly

```
(2008-05-11T15:30:00+2 ---> 2008-05-11T13:30:00Z)
```

with SQL functions.

I need to implement this using MySql preferrably, not using stored procedures.

Answer (score 8):

Try this

To convert from GMT to local time:

```
select DATEADD(hour,DATEDIFF (hour, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()),MyGmtDateTime) as LocalDateTime
```

To convert from local time to GMT:

```
select DATEADD(hour,DATEDIFF (hour, GETDATE(), GETUTCDATE()),MyLocalDateTime) as GmtDateTime
```

Comment: It is better to change `hour` to `minute` to support timezones with offset that is not perfect hours, e.g. +03:30

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly, there is no way to find out the time zone from time+offset because the mapping is not unique. Several time zones may have the same offset.

Look at this example where multiple time zone have the same offset.

```
(GMT-06:00) Saskatchewan
(GMT-06:00) Guadalajara, Mexico City, Monterrey - Old
(GMT-06:00) Guadalajara, Mexico City, Monterrey - New
(GMT-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)
(GMT-06:00) Central America
```

ADDED: Now I see you asked for something else.

Okay, if the offset in your datetimes is always the same, you can try this transformation.

```
DECLARE @DateTimeWithOffset datetimeoffset
DECLARE @JustDateTime datetime

SET @DateTimeWithOffset = '2008-05-11 15:30:00 + 02:00'

SELECT @DateTimeWithOffset = SWITCHOFFSET (@DateTimeWithOffset, '00:00')

SELECT @JustDateTime = CAST (@DateTimeWithOffset AS datetime)
```

This is to give you the idea. I don't have an SQL 2008 right at hand so I haven't tested that. May not work.

Comment: I think the OP means GMT by "TZ" - note title of post.

Comment: i've added a conversion example above

Comment: Note that `SWITCHOFFSET` is new for SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty rusty with my SQL built-in functions, but in the absence of any standard function, you could write a stored procedure to do the work.  Then you could invoke it as part of your SELECT statement:

```
SELECT to_GMT(invoice_date) from INVOICES
```

Comment: probably better to build a Scalar Function, it can be one-offed and operate on result-set more efficiently.  Especially if the date is needing to be changed on a query.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear from your question, but I assume you have the values as a string. If so, then extract everything except the offset as a `datetime`, also get the offset as a `datetime`, then use the sign to calculate the final result (T-SQL, 2005):

```
DECLARE @withOffset varchar(30);
SET @withOffset = '2008-05-11T15:30:00+2:00';
PRINT N'Original: ' + CAST(@withOffset AS nvarchar);

DECLARE @dt datetime;
SET @dt = CONVERT(datetime, LEFT(@withOffset, 19), 126);
PRINT N'dt=' + CONVERT(nvarchar, @dt, 127);

DECLARE @ofs datetime;
SET @ofs = CONVERT(datetime, SUBSTRING(@withOffset, 21, LEN(@withOffset) - 21), 108);
PRINT N'ofs=' + CAST(@ofs AS nvarchar);

IF (SUBSTRING(@withOffset, 19, 1) = '+')
BEGIN
    SET @dt = DATEADD(hour, DATEPART(hour, @ofs), @dt);
    SET @dt = DATEADD(minute, DATEPART(minute, @ofs), @dt);
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @dt = DATEADD(hour, -DATEPART(hour, @ofs), @dt);
    SET @dt = DATEADD(minute, -DATEPART(minute, @ofs), @dt);
END;

PRINT N'dt=' + CONVERT(nvarchar, @dt, 127);
```

Answer (score 1):

the solution will likely depend of your RDBMS. In Oracle this would work:

```
SQL> SELECT to_timestamp_tz('2008-05-11T15:30:00+2',
  2                         'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ssTZH')
  3         AT TIME ZONE 'GMT' gmt_time
  4    FROM dual;

GMT_TIME
----------------------------------
11/05/08 13:30:00,000000000 GMT
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the SQL function `CONVERT_TZ(dt,from_tz,to_tz)`.

> CONVERT_TZ() converts a datetime value dt from the time zone given by
>   from_tz to the time zone given by to_tz and returns the resulting
>   value.

Example:

```
UPDATE this_table
SET this_table_date_gmt = (
    SELECT CONVERT_TZ(this_date, '+00:00', '-02:00')
)
```

Reference : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz